# Dr. prescribed Ondansetron/Zofran for migraines & says it'll help with weight loss too. How effective is it for either (migraines/weight loss)?

Tags: medications, weight-loss, migraine

I have suffered from migraines since my childhood, but I never grew out of it. For all my life, I've taken all sorts of blockers, but a new doctor recently suggested that I should take Ondansetron/Zofran at 16mg a day, and see if this improves how I feel.

He also mentioned that it might help me lose weight, which is something I've struggled with because I have hypothyroidism, PCOS, and have had over 15 surgeries on my ankles/feet (so despite earnest efforts, nothing really budges).

1. **How effective is Ondansetron/Zofran for treating migraines?**
2. **How effective is Ondansetron/Zofran for helping to lose weight?**

How soon will I notice a difference, if any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Your question contains two parts. So I will address them separately.*

**First here a small background on ondansetron**: Ondansetron is a selective **antagonist at 5-HT3 receptors**. It is most frequently used in the prevention of chemotherapy-induced nausea and vomiting.

> **How effective is Ondansetron/Zofran for treating migraines?**

Ondansetron doesn't belong to the drug used in the management of nausea and vomiting in migraine. **Actually, headache are the most common side effects of odansetron** [1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9539593?dopt=Abstract) [2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9416710?dopt=Abstract), so it is definitely not suitable in your case. Although you seem to have tested a lot of drugs against nausea and vomiting, the review by [Lainez et al](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3798203/) provides an excellent **summary of the recommendations for nause and vomiting management in migraine** (below). This might help you.

[image]

> **How effective is Ondansetron/Zofran for helping to lose weight?**

I haven't found a study showing a link between ondansetron and weight loss. Though, recently, an experimental [study](http://www.nature.com/ijo/journal/v33/n12/full/ijo2009191a.html) conducted in mice, showed that **tropisetron** (which is also a 5-HT3R antagonist) *reduced intestinal motility and almost completely blocked weight gain associated with glucose feeding*.